# Superhuman Level - Pandas DataFrame Reshaping because of Duplicates

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape

**Do you like puzzles that only superhumans can solve? This is the final test to prove such an ability.**

A single company might get different levels of funding (seed, a) from multiple banks possibly at different times.

Let's look at the data then the story to get a better picture.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'id':[1,2,2,3,4],'company':['alpha','beta','beta','alpha','alpha'],'bank':['z', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'j'], 
    'rd': ['seed', 'seed', 'seed', 'a', 'a'], 'funding': [100, 200, 200, 300, 50],
   'date': ['2006-12-01', '2004-09-01', '2004-09-01', '2007-05-01', '2007-09-01']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id','company', 'round', 'bank', 'funding', 'date'])
df
```

## Yields:

```
   id  company        rd   bank    funding        date
0   1    alpha      seed      z        100  2006-12-01
1   2     beta      seed      x        200  2004-09-01
2   2     beta      seed      y        200  2004-09-01
3   3    alpha         a      z        300  2007-05-01
4   4    alpha         a      j         50  2007-09-01
```

## Desired Output:

```
   company     bank_seed   funding_seed      date_seed    bank_a  funding_a      date_a 
0    alpha             z            100     2006-12-01     [z,j]        350  2007-09-01
1     beta         [x,y]            200     2004-09-01      None       None        None
```

As you can see, I am not a superhuman but shall try to explain my thought process.

#### *Let's look at company alpha*

Company alpha first got seed money for $100 from bank z in late 2006. A few months later, their investors were very happy with their progress so bank z gave them money ($300 more!). However, Company alpha needed a little more cash but had to go to some random Swiss bank j to stay alive. Bank j reluctantly gave $50 more. Yay! They now have $350 from their updated 'a' round ending in September 2007.

Company beta is pretty new. They got funding totaling $200 from two different banks. But wait... there's nothing in here about their round 'a'. That's okay we'll put None for now and check back with them later.

**The issue is that Company alpha sucks and got money from the Swiss...**
This is my non-working code that had worked on a subset of my data - it won't work here.

```
import itertools

unique_company = df.company.unique()
df_indexed = df.set_index(['company', 'rd'])
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(itertools.product(unique_company, list(df.rd.unique()))))
reindexed = df_indexed.reindex(index, fill_value=0)

reindexed = reindexed.unstack().applymap(lambda cell: 0 if '1970-01-01' in str(cell) else cell)

working_df = pd.DataFrame(reindexed.iloc[:, 
reindexed.columns.get_level_values(0).isin(['company', 'funding'])].to_records())
```

If you know how to solve part of this problem, go ahead and put it below. Thank you in advance for taking the time to look at this! :)

Lastly, if you want to see how my code *does* work. Then, do this but you lose so much valuable info...

```
 df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='id')
 df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='rd')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a pre-processing step to spread out the funding across records with the same `'id'` and `'date'`

```
df.funding /= df.groupby(['id', 'date']).funding.transform('count')
```

Then process

```
d1 = df.groupby(['company', 'round']).agg(
    dict(bank=lambda x: tuple(x), funding='sum', date='last')
).unstack().sort_index(1, 1)

d1.columns = d1.columns.to_series().map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)

d1


           bank funding       date    bank funding       date
round         a       a          a    seed    seed       seed
company                                                      
alpha    (z, j)   350.0 2007-09-01    (z,)   100.0 2006-12-01
beta       None     NaN        NaT  (x, y)   200.0 2004-09-01
```

Comment: Tuple is a great idea, I tried list(x) but it didn't work, any idea why? +1

Comment: @A-Za-z hashable vs unhashable

Comment: You're so close! Column "funding_seed" for the beta company is actually 200 as they received 200 combined from two different banks.

Comment: @mitchell-reynolds then why do you have 200 from two separate banks?

Comment: I don't think it's hashable vs unhashable.  Using `lambda x: [x.tolist()]` will let you jam in a list of lists.

Comment: @piRSquared my thoughts exactly! My original dataset has this type of format where an arbitrary number of banks give some amount of funding to a company. Sadly, it's just messy and duplicated as you see above.

Comment: @mitchell-reynolds `'alpha'` has `350` from two separate banks.  How am supposed to tell the difference between those two records for `'alpha'` and the two records for `'beta'`?

Comment: @piRSquared great question. The `date` column values are the same for `beta` whereas `alpha` has two different dates. Or, the `df.id` is different too.

Comment: @mitchell-reynolds that should do it.

Comment: I love this! I'm going to tweak the tuple to a list as I couldn't get @root 's `lambda x: [x.tolist()]` snippet to work. You all are awesome! Thank you superhumans :)

Comment: Hi @root I've tried the `[x.tolist()]` yet I get an error saying "Function does not reduce". Did you change anything else? Thanks!

Comment: @mitchell-reynolds:  No, but it never "worked" in the way you wanted it to anyways.  `[x.tolist()]` produces a list of lists structure, not a regular list.  I only mentioned it as a counterexample to the assertion that tuples work and lists didn't due to hashable vs. unhashable.

Answer (score 3):

Groupby, aggregate and unstack will get you close to what you want

```
df.groupby(['company', 'round']).agg({'bank': lambda x: ','.join(x), 'funding': 'sum', 'date': 'max'}).unstack().reset_index()

df.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]
```

You get

```
    company_    bank_a  bank_seed   funding_a   funding_seed  date_a    date_seed
0   alpha       z,j     z           350.0       100.0         2007-09-01 2006-12-01
1   beta        None    x,y         NaN         400.0         None        2004-09-01
```

Comment: Very very close! the funding_seed should be 200 since they received 200 combined from x and y.

Comment: I am not sure if that can be handled as your data shows it at both the places. If we try to take the maximum or unique of the two from bank x and bank y, it will impact company alpha's value